# What is the advantage of generating and modeling a codeword all at zero?

Tags: matlab, encoding, decoding

In channel coding, you often generate and modulate the codeword all at zero to test performance of a decoder.

(For example `codeword = zeros (1,n)`; `x = 2*codeword-1`)

in other cases the codeword is generated and modulate from :`word = rand(1,n)`; `codeword = mod(word*G,2)`;`x = 2*codeword-1`).

`n`: length of codeword; `G`: Generator matrix.

What is the difference between its two ways of proceeding and what is the advantage of generating and modeling a code word all at zero?

Comment: If the code is [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_code) (as is often the case), any codeword has the same behaviour in terms of error performance. The all-zero codeword is just simpler to use. For example, the distance from any other word C to the all-zero word is just the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) of C

Comment: Thanks @Luis Mendo. I understand now. So, if I do simulations with its two options, I have to have the same curves?

Comment: If the code is linear yes, you will get the same error curves, up to statistical fluctuations

Comment: I have done the tests on my decoder (ordering statistics decoding) and I find a good error curve with the all-zero codeword, but with the second option I find an error curve almost contante.My decoder must have a problem? I use the Golay code (24,12,8).

Comment: No idea with the information you provide, sorry

Comment: No problem,thank you for your explanation which allowed me to understand the advantage of generating the all-zero code word.